# Hibernate issue - Invalid column name

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have added two columns in the sql to get the values through hibernate.My databse is oracle and those fields datatype i number. So i have created the beans with long and (tried Integer too) but when retrieving the values(executing the valuesquery).

Its giving me an error

```
org.hibernate.type.LongType - could not read column value from result set
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3711)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:2806)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getLong(OracleResultSet.java:444)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.ResultSet_oracle_jdbc_driver_OracleResultSetImpl.getLong(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.type.LongType.get(LongType.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:189)
```

tABLE DEFINITION :

```
    CREATE TABLE "PRODUCTLIST"
(
   PRICELIST_PUBLISH_KEY decimal(22) NOT NULL,
   PRODUCT_NBR varchar2(54) NOT NULL,
   PRODUCT_KEY decimal(22),
   PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION varchar2(360),
   PRODUCT_FAMILY_NBR varchar2(30),
   PRODUCT_FAMILY_DESCR varchar2(180),
   PRODUCT_GROUP_NBR varchar2(30),
   PRODUCT_GROUP_DESCR varchar2(180),
   PRODUCT_LINE_NBR varchar2(30),
   PRODUCT_LINE_DESCR varchar2(180),
   PRODUCT_CLASS_CODE varchar2(6),
   LAST_PP_GENERATED_DATE_KEY decimal(22),
   LAST_PP_GENERATED_DATE date,
   PUBLISH_PERIOD_KEY decimal(22) NOT NULL,
   PUBLISH_PERIOD_DATE date,
   PL_KEY decimal(22),
   PRODUCTLIST varchar2(750),
   SALES_KEY decimal(22),
   PRODUCT varchar2(60),
   DM_EXTRACTED_BY_USER varchar2(90)
)
```

sql :

```
        Query query =  session.createSQLQuery(channelQuery)
                                   .addScalar("PRODUCT",Hibernate.STRING)
                                 .addScalar("PRODUCTLIST",Hibernate.STRING)
                                 .addScalar("PRODUCTKEY",Hibernate.LONG)
                                 .addScalar("SALESKEY",Hibernate.LONG)
                           .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SearchResult.class));          
               return query.list();
             }
  });
```

Please help me to fix the issue ?

Comment: Please show us the table definition (`CREATE TABLE ...`) and the actual query you are running.

Comment: SELECT distinct p.product, p.productprice, p.PL_KEY, p.SALES_KEY   FROM  productlist pub  WHERE p.productnbr in ('1002102') Which is running in toad , but while ruuning through hibernate giving me an error invalid column name.

Comment: are u executing this query with hibernate? with sql?

Comment: Particularly after added fields "p.PL_KEY, p.SALES_KEY" its getting error.before there was no error. These two fields datatype is number in oracle.

Comment: I'm expecting in hibernate

Comment: could you update your question? with your code? query and mapping of the class? and table definition as asked before?

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Edit your question. And the table definition (as `CREATE TABLE`) is still missing

Comment: What table column does the field `productprice` is mapped to? Show us the entity -> table mapping?

Comment: You should revise the query you put in your comment: you use `p` as the table alias, but declare it as `pub`, you use `p.productprice` in the `SELECT` clause, but there is no such field in the `CREATE TABLE...` you added to your question, and the same occurs with the field `p.productnbr` in the `WHERE` clause. Are you really sure the query is running **without error** in toad?

Answer (score 3):

In your table definition, I can't see all the fields you're using in the `addScalar()` methods: there are no `PRODUCTKEY` nor `SALESKEY` fields. Instead I can see a `PRODUCT_KEY` and a `SALES_KEY` fields (underscores). I think you should use the correct name of the fields in the `addScalar()` methods.

But if your query is the one you put in your comments, you have to correct some details:

1. **you should use** `p` **instead of** `pub` **as alias for the table name**. As there is only one table in the query, you can suppress the alias.
2. In your `SELECT` clause, `p.productprice` **is not an existing field in your table**. Maybe you want to use `p.pricelist` instead.
3. In your `WHERE` clause, `p.productnbr` **is not an existing field in your table**. You should use `p.product_nbr` instead.
4. Then you should change the field names in the `addScalar()` methods to match those you are using in the query.

Modified query

```
SELECT distinct p.product, p.productlist, p.PL_KEY, p.SALES_KEY
FROM productlist p
WHERE p.product_nbr in ('1002102')
```

Your code should be:

```
Query query =  session.createSQLQuery(channelQuery)
    .addScalar("PRODUCT",Hibernate.STRING)
    .addScalar("PRODUCTLIST",Hibernate.STRING)
    .addScalar("PL_KEY",Hibernate.LONG)
    .addScalar("SALES_KEY",Hibernate.LONG)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SearchResult.class));          
return query.list();
```

If you define aliases in your query, then you can use the alias names instead of the field names. For example, with this query:

```
SELECT distinct p.product, p.productlist, p.PL_KEY as PRODUCTKEY, p.SALES_KEY as SALESKEY
FROM productlist p
WHERE p.product_nbr in ('1002102')
```

you can use the following code (it's your original code):

```
Query query =  session.createSQLQuery(channelQuery)
    .addScalar("PRODUCT",Hibernate.STRING)
    .addScalar("PRODUCTLIST",Hibernate.STRING)
    .addScalar("PRODUCTKEY",Hibernate.LONG)
    .addScalar("SALESKEY",Hibernate.LONG)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(SearchResult.class));          
return query.list();
```